# How to avoide throwing exception if an answer is 404 with Guzzle?

Tags: php, guzzle

Not result is result too in my case. But `Guzzle` throws me an exception and as result, my promise has 'rejected' status. Is it possible to change this behavior?

[image]

If it's impossible, can I get the status code? If I write something like:

```
$item['reason']->code
```

I have an error. I think this field is private. And there is no `getStatusCode` method for this object.

So I need 200 and 404 results. 500 and so on is not important for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normally we just catch those exceptions and provide some logic like:

```
$emptyResult = [];
try{
    //your code that should work goes here
    $result = getItemsFromApi();
    return json_encode($result);
} catch(ClientException $e){
  if($e->getCode() == '404'){
     /*warning: in our case body is json already, not sure if your is the same */
     return $e->getResponse()->getBody();
  }
}
```